# unable to unsubscribe BehaviorSubject in Angular 5 Applicaiton

Tags: rxjs, angular5

I am working with Angular 5 , i am using BehaviorSubject as below  (Rxjs version is "rxjs": "^5.1.0", as i mentioned in package.json files)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getConfirmReturnValue();
}

getConfirmReturnValue() {
    this.confirmService.getReturnValue()
        .takeWhile(() => this.alive = true)
        .subscribe(
            suc => {
                console.log('return value::', suc);
                if (suc != 0 && suc.hasOwnProperty('returnValue')) {
            this.deleteLanguage(suc); }
        });
 }
```

in onDestroy method i am unsubscribing as below

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.alive = false;
}
```

but i am getting the below error in browser console

```
at SafeSubscriber._next (languages-view.component.ts:143)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:239)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:186)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:126)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:90)
    at TakeWhileSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operators/takeWhile.js.TakeWhileSubscriber.nextOrComplete (takeWhile.js:84)
    at TakeWhileSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operators/takeWhile.js.TakeWhileSubscriber._next (takeWhile.js:79)
    at TakeWhileSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:90)
    at BehaviorSubject.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
```

Comment: `this.alive = true` => `this.alive == true`. Or just `this.alive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function for the `takeWhile` operator requires you to return a boolean. Right now you're returning `undefined` because `this.alive = true` is just an assignment and this itself doesn't return anything.

So instead you should do this:

```
.takeWhile(() => this.alive) // or this.alive === true
```

Be aware that `takeWhile` will be invoked only when `this.confirmService.getReturnValue()` emits a value so when the component gets destroyed it might not immediately mean that the chain is disposed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed takeWhile(--) and did below, it resolves my issue

```
getConfirmReturnValue() {
      this.subscription1 = this.confirmService.getReturnValue()
        .subscribe(
            suc => {
                console.log('return value::', suc);
                if (suc != 0 && suc.hasOwnProperty('returnValue')) {
            this.deleteLanguage(suc); }
        });
    }

ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription1.unsubscribe();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy using below code.

```
getConfirmReturnValue() {
this.var = this.confirmService.getReturnValue()
    .takeWhile(() => this.alive = true)
    .subscribe(
        suc => {
            console.log('return value::', suc);
            if (suc != 0 && suc.hasOwnProperty('returnValue')) {
        this.deleteLanguage(suc); }
    });} 

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.var.unsubscribe();}
```

Comment: but alive is declared as boolean in varible declaration section

Comment: To unsubscribe you have to write down use subscribedVariableName.unsubscribe() method.